# character to integer conversion in fortran

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I have a date time value declared as character in this way "1985-01-01-00:00" and I want to extract the year, month and day as integer. I don't know the exact command in FORTRAN language.

Comment: you might want to label your questions just `fortran`, more people will see them that way.

Answer (score 6):

For example:

```
program zz
  character(20) :: ch = "1985-01-01-00:00"
  integer yyyy,mm,dd

  read(ch(1:4),'(i)') yyyy
  read(ch(6:7),'(i)') mm
  read(ch(9:10),'(i)') dd

  write(*,*) yyyy, mm, dd
end program zz
```

Comment: You need to add an integer width: "(i5)" and such.