# fortran internal read - convert character to integer

Tags: fortran, format-conversion

I have browsed through many articles (i.e. [character to integer conversion in fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900417/character-to-integer-conversion-in-fortran)) which suggest a solution to the problem.
I just can't get it working although I think I follow the suggestions given.
The main problem would be to have a text which I would like to store as an integer (don't ask why, the code is 35 year old which I would like to get up and running again).
The minimum working example looks like:

```
program test
  integer :: LTS
  CHARACTER (len=1)  :: UBF
  UBF = "U"
  read(UBF,'(i1)')  LTS
  stop
  END
```

I compile with 'gfortran' (no matter whether v.4.8.5. or v.11) and the error is:
'At line 5 of file minimal.f
Fortran runtime error: Bad value during integer read'

Printing out the variable UBF, I can see the string 'U'. It's there.
I expected to get an integer value for 'U' in LTS.

I guess, I don't see the forest for the trees.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
The OS is Redhat 7.9 if that had any influence.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Hi, I tried '1', which works. AS I mentioned, the program is really old where people did funny things. In the version I havem the character string is stored as an integer. I am acutally looking for a way, where I can maybe convert the string (which in the original version is 5 characters) to an integer. I know, it sounds stupid. I tried ICHAR which is not the right way either -- any suggestions?

Comment: "In the version I havem the character string is stored as an integer"  - are you talking Hollerith? What went wrong with your `ichar` attempt?

Comment: To reinforce what @francescalus wrote - it's difficult for us to fix problems you don't show us.

Comment: ICHAR - as I read it only takes a character, but I need a string. For whatever reason, the legacy code stores the string as an integer. As you do call-by-address, the legacy code did not bother that, although it's against all standards. I try to mimmick that somehow, but I guess I have to rewrite that part. The original code reads '          LTS(412) ="U -BF"', where LTS is an integer (array).

Comment: You can always do `lts = transfer("u",lts)` or `lts = transfer("   u",lts)`. Does that help? BTW, did you look what the mentioned Hollerith is?

Comment: Dear Vladimir, thanks. That was what I was looking for. Is there also a way to reverse that operation? To transfer the INTEGER back in a string (from which I know the size since I transfered it before)?

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer bit patterns between variables of different type using the standard [transfer function](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/TRANSFER.html). The first argument is what you are converting and the other argument has the type to which you are converting.

For example,

```
number = transfer("u",number)
string = transfer(number, string)
```

Comment: Dear Vladimir, thanks you very much for the detailed description. That solves my problem.